# The project * needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I starting the project the following error appears:

```
The project TestProject.Android needs to be deployed before it can be started. Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager.
```

In the `Configuration Manager` **Build** and **Deploy** configurations enabled for Any CPU.

> Note: reproduce only on Visual Studio 2019. On the previous version (2017)
>   all works as expected.

Comment: Could you share pictures of your configuration mappings for you solution and for the individual android project?

Comment: I had the same issue on the latest Visal Studio 2019. Dont know if its a bug. On the older version of Visual Studio and in mac it worked okay for me

Comment: Yeah, add a note. On the VS 2017 works as expected

Comment: @a.tarasevich Were you able to get this to work ? I am having the same problem

Comment: @snowCrabs No, I started using VS 2017 for this project..

Comment: Same issue with VS 2019. Wasted two days trying to figure out a solution :(

Comment: close VS;  back up the `.vs, bin, obj` folders; then remove them from the solution folder and re-open the solution.  Note: the .vs folder is hidden so you will have to show hidden files/folders to remove it.  If it was working before and not now then `.vs` one of the folders that could have changed.  It will get automatically regenerated when you open the solution again with default values

Answer (score 4):

You can simply change the settings in your **Solution** as:

```
 right-click the Solution -->then go to "Configuration Manager" -->then check "deploy" for your required platform project.
```

Hope!! It will work..

Comment: Build succeeded and Deployment was successful to pixel_2_xl_pie_9_0_-_api_28 but still got the error message.